# Properties of a smooth space-filling curve

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

[image: Double cotangent centers]

Recently I ran into the notion of a [$t$-central angle point (42614-42620)](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETCPart22.html) center of a triangle. I plotted the curve for arbitrary $t$, see above. Amusingly, *any* center lies on the curve for some $t$! (Clarification: For a given center identity, $t$ may vary if the shape of the triangle varies, thus  e.g. the barycenter lies on the curve but is no $t$-center!) Also, the curve is infinitely many times differentiable everywhere except at a finite number of singularities. There are two types $C$ and $K$: Three are the triangle corners (where infinitely many lines $C$ross), one should have tangent $K$inks.

So let $S$ be any space filling curve that is infinitely many times differentiable everywhere except at a finite number of singularities.

- Can there be other types than $C$ and $K$?
- Is there some simple "Eulerish" formula that connects their numbers?

[The Wiki singularity page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)) was not particularly helpful. (It states that 3-4, depending on count, type of singularities exist.)

Comment: By Sard's theorem, a smooth curve can't be space filling.

Comment: Maybe the OP meant 'dense' instead?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Uh-oh, I didn't know there was a difference between "space filling" and "dense". I mean, each point of ${\mathbb R}^2$ except the $K$ one lies on the curve! Is this "except" the problem? Then I edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on your way towards rediscovering the [Poincaré–Hopf index formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem).  As the comments point out, this is not really a question about space-filling curves.  Instead it is a question about smooth foliations of the plane with finitely many, isolated, singularities. Each singularities has an "index". These add to give the Euler characteristic of the plane (or sphere, depending on how we arrange things).

Comment: Ha, I knew it. (What I don't know is "higher" math, so again I apologize if I didn't get the technical terms right.)